# Django with mongodb:DatabaseError with .distinct()

Tags: django, mongodb, distinct

I uses django and mongodb with django-mongodb-engine(0.52) and try to get the list of distinct records from db.

the model:

```
class relation(models.Model):
    plateNumber = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    siteId = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    vehicleTime = models.BigIntegerField()
```

the template:

```
{% for line in lines %}
    <tr>
        <th>{{ line.plateNumber }}</th>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

the view:

```
lines = relation.objects.order_by(vehicleTime").distinct()
```

I print lines.query for detail

```
SELECT DISTINCT vsdweb_relation.id, vsdweb_relation.plateNumber, vsdweb_relation.siteId, vsdweb_relation.vehicleTime, FROM vsdweb_relation ORDER BY vsdweb_relation.plateNumber ASC
```

When I used the distinct(), I get the "This query is not supported by the database.", but I checked the changelog of mongodb engine. It supports dictinct() since 0.50.

Any ideas on why this would be happening?

Comment: ``.order_by().distinct()`` is critical always

Comment: ok, I found the solution, just add objects = MongoDBManager() to the model. But new problem, I used lines = relation.objects.filter(**filter).distinct("plateNumber") but get only a list of plateNumber. What I want is a list of the [plateNumber,siteId,vehicleTime].How can I achieve this?

Comment: what about ``values()`` ?